# Not entering sleep mode while MBP's Lid closed while using external monitor?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have Retina Macbook Pro 15' connected to an external monitor.
Is it possible to close the MBP's lid and still use the external monitor without entering sleep mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should work without any special extra configurations. You only need to have the macbook connected to an external display and also have an external keyboard (probably it also works without the external keyboard, but what will you do without it :p). If you have the lid closed and macbook is "sleeping", you can wake it up (by pressing any keyboard key) and start using it with the external display without requiring to open the lid.

Cheers!

Comment: OK, I've just done that but the external monitor doesn't wake up.

Comment: Does the external display work when you have the lid open?

Comment: yes, it works perfectly when the lid is open.

Comment: weird... here are some discussion on that topic: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3131, it says you should have the macbook connected to the power and have the external keyboard/mouse connected. Take a look.

Comment: Oh, it isn't connected to the power and the mouse is connected to the screen. ( actually I'd prefer that both the mouse and the keyboard to be connected to the usb ports in the monitor)

Comment: OK, after I'm using the power + keyboard + mouse it works with the lid closed. Do you know whether it's "dangerous" to work that way, due to maybe heating?

Comment: Great! I do not think you will have problems working with lid closed, many people use their macbook like that (I have it open most of the time, since I use it for "auxiliary" activities in my work)... I think the ventilation works pretty well even with the lid closed. You can install some small app to see your macbook temperature to control that, but I do not think you will have problems! Cheers!